# Can connect to Apache 2 test page, but no to Mediawiki

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, mediawiki

I've set up Mediawiki on Centos 6 according to this article:
https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Running_MediaWiki_on_Red_Hat_Linux

Works fine locally, but when I attempt to connect from outside my server to http://IPADDRESS/mediawiki it says connection refused.  The weird thing is I can connect to the Apache2 test page just fine at http://IPADDRESS and my Nagios webpage at http://IPADDRESS/nagios

Why am I unable to connect to my Mediawiki site only?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like MySQL connectivity issue.

Is there a chance that you MediaWiki settings refer to the MySQL server using address other than 'localhost'?

Comment: "Works fine locally" , so why should it be a MySQL issue?

Comment: Nope, I left it as localhost

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.  Had to edit the LocalSettings.php file $wgServer variable to point to my server name instead of 'localhost'

Comment: This means MySQL is listening on an external interface.  If you don't have your firewall configured to block external access and you don't have your grants set up to allow local access only this could result in a security problem.